# Put results of PCA into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pca

I have performed PCA.

I would like to put those results in a dataframe. More specifically, I want to create a dataframe with two rows and two columns (principal components after doing PCA on wc_accounts)

I tried with:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit(wc_accounts)
data = pca.components_
print(data)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])
```

However, the last line gives the error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (828, 2), indices imply (2, 2)`

Because its so big I can't print data in full. Essentially it is an array of two arrays (of length 828) of floats:

```
[[-1.57759323e-02 -1.57759323e-02 -0.00000000e+00 ... -1.57759323e-02
  -3.15518646e-02  1.57759323e-02]
 [-9.99844616e-01  2.06534552e-04  0.00000000e+00 ...  2.06534552e-04
   4.13069105e-04 -2.06534552e-04]]
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the data variable.

Comment: nope, this works, assuming `data` has the shape indicated here

Comment: Are we to assume that each pair of data is PCA1 and PCA2? Each list of list should contain 2 elements if you want to read it in that way.

Comment: I want to create a dataframe with two rows and two columns (principal components after doing PCA on wc_accounts)

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you want to use the transform data and not 'pca.components_' which contains unit vectors defining principal components.
See here for an example of what you wish to achieve.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 8)))
df.head()

pca     = PCA(n_components=4).fit(df)
columns = ['pca_comp_%i' % i for i in range(4)]
df_pca  = pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(df), columns=columns, index=df.index)
df_pca.head()
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the orientation of `data` is transposed relative to how `pd.DataFrame` expects it.

So, you can use `index` instead and then transpose:

```
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['principal component 1', 'principal component 2']).T
```